# Load files with right way

Tags: r

I am new in the use of R. I try to handle .xls file and the data have this format:

```
num                         day
 1                 2011-1-1 00:00:01
 2                 2011-1-2 00:00:02
 3                 2011-1-3 00:00:03
```

I try to load the file:

```
 example <- read.xls(/path/exam.xls)
```

but it gives me but this error

```
Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
  perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(xlsx)

read.xlsx("/path/exam.xls",1)
```